# nagios behind reverse proxy

Tags: apache2, nagios3, reverse-proxy

I installed nagios core in Ubuntu. After that, I setup a reverse proxy in Apache.

Now nagios is not working. I could not find what is the issue. I looked on the internet and changed the Apache configuration file, but am still not able to get nagios working behind a reverse proxy.

Here is my Apache config file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS

        ProxyPass /nagios/cgi-bin http://127.0.0.1/usr/local/nagios/sbin/
        ProxyPassReverse /nagios/cgi-bin http://127.0.0.1/usr/local/nagios/sbin/

        ProxyPass /nagios http://127.0.0.1/nagios/
        ProxyPassReverse /nagios http://127.0.0.1/nagios/

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off

        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
        RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/nagios/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/nagios
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access `http://MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS/nagios` I am getting "Service Unavailable". I checked nagios with `systemctl`, and it shows as running.

PS: I did all `a2dissite` and `a2ensite` that are needed to disable previous Apache config file and enable the new one.

Comment: What your Apache config? What is 'not working'? A 404? An internal service error? You not being able to access the reverse proxy at all? What port is  nagios running un?

Comment: I added my apache2 config file and the error message I'm getting. thanks.

Comment: You have to point the proxy to Nagios, not back to Apache...

Comment: In which line?
When I installed nagios without reverse proxy I was able to access it using the URL : http://My-Server-IP-ADDRESS/nagios

Comment: Then why do you need a proxy?

Comment: I need a proxy because I have two other applications I use to access then through a reverse proxy. When I activated the reverse proxy, I wasn't able to access nagios so I'm trying to find how to configure apache to get access to nagios.

Comment: Oh, so you dont actually want to proxy Nagios but the Apache is also proxying other locations? You have to restore the config to the point where Nagios is working, then you can override the `ProxyPass` with a `!` - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass If this does not help, you have to share the whole config...

Comment: That gave me access to nagios interface with some errors like could not access services "page not found", this needs more config changes. I want nagios to be behind a reverse proxy as all other services I have. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, if you really want to do that... Just set up another Apache on a different port and point the proxy to it.

Comment: You mean, I can setup two apache servers in the same machine? 
My apache reverse proxy works fine with other applications I have. The issue is juste with nagios.
I want to keep juste port 80 open in my server and use apache reverse proxy to reach all the other applications II have in my server including nagios-core.
There is not two much documentation on how to setup nagios behind a reverse proxy.

I used this one, the only I found, but didn't work for me : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFOJSzNaEFw&list=PLgxdybVSatpyCAEGID6CvvUtkdXeX_KFN&index=123